# Clone ResourceDictionary Object

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

Say that I have the object:

```
<Grid x:Key"FooGrid>
   <!--Content Here-->
</Grid>
```

And I normally reference it by something like:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FooGrid}"/>
```

And while this works, if I call it a second time, it removes the first use and moves it to the requested second use.

Clearly there's an issue of my method of calling the resource. What would be a better way of going about this, if I want a unique instance of the object, similar to what Style can create?

I'd use style, but as I understand it Style doesn't support defined content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [x:Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx) attribute to do this, e.g.:

```
<Grid x:Key"FooGrid" x:Shared="False"> 
   <!--Content Here--> 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse-me if my english is bad..

This happens,because the element is logical child of other element.
But the ContentPresenter is not a ContentControl, then he do this approach.

if you try the same thing with a ContentControl, you get a Runtime Error.

See:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.content

Att,
Allan

Answer (score 0):

I used "a little sheep" answer to add

`x:Shared="False"`

but it ruined structure of VisualBrush, so I added to code

`VisualBrush vb = Application.Current.Resources["MyBrushName"] as VisualBrush;
VisualBrush newVB = vb.Clone();`

and it justified my endeavours.


Using only `.Clone()` doesn't work.